# How to backup/restore a contacts in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Hello `sackoverflow` I'm trying to develop an application which can backup and restore contacts, my code is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

Cursor cursor;
ArrayList<String> vCard ;
String vfile;
FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = null;
Button btnRestorects = null;
Button btnBackupCts = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnRestorects = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRstCts);
    btnBackupCts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBackCts);

    vfile = "contacts.vcf";
    final String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/"+ vfile;

    final File f = new File(storage_path);

    btnBackupCts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (!f.exists())
                    f.createNewFile();
                mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storage_path, false);
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            getVcardString();
        }
    });

    btnRestorects.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            final Intent intent = new Intent();

            final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String tmptype = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("vcf");
            final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/contacts.vcf");

            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),tmptype);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private void getVcardString() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    vCard = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null&&cursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int i =0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
        {

            get(cursor);
            Log.d("TAG", "Contact "+(i+1)+"VcF String is"+vCard.get(i));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");
    }
    try 
    {
        mFileOutputStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void get(Cursor cursor)
{
    //cursor.moveToFirst();
    String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
    AssetFileDescriptor fd;
    try 
    {
        fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
        fis.read(buf);
        String vcardstring= new String(buf);
        vCard.add(vcardstring);

        mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());

    }
    catch (Exception e1) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

So far my code was backing up the contact but only name and contact number, but not retrieving the information like whether the contact is starred or not. Please help me in solving this riddle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to restore:

```
final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
  String tmptype = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("vcf");
  final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/contacts.vcf");
  Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/x-vcard");
  startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)), MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("vcf"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Select App"));
```