# How to avoid duplicate contact restore in android

Tags: android

I'm doing an android application which does Backup & Restore Phone contacts into remote server as `vcf` file type.Suppose if I have 5 contacts, I could do Backup it into server well & good. After that If I delete 2 contacts in the mobile,now totally 3. But server has 5 contacts. Then If I restore from server, that 3 Contacts will gets duplicated. Below is my code. How could I avoid that duplication while restore contacts.

Code:

```
final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String tmptype = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("vcf");
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/contacts.vcf");
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/x-vcard");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What datastructure do you use ? You should use HashSet

Comment: Hi., I used this code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086409/how-to-backup-restore-a-contacts-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Add your contact in ArrayList < String> arrDupContact and while delete contact remove contact from arrDupContact also.While fetching contact from server check whether it contain that particular contact or not it is contain then bypass it, if not the add it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Can I have any code sample regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I would you Set cont = new HashSet(), becasuse HashSet don`t allow duplicates by default. 
Please find this quick summary here:
http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/java-collections-framework-summary-table

Please find a massive summary here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html